# About Android Open Automotive Protocol , device support

Tags: android, protocols

I have some queries on AOA(Android Open Automotive) protocol

1)How do we came to know whether an android device is supporting Android Open Automotive Protocol or not...

2)Is there any drivers /software is required to install on the device in order support

3)Please let me know is there any device as of now is having built-in support of this AOA  protocol?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do u refer to Open Automotive Alliance (OAA) or Android Open Accessory Protocol (AOA) [https://source.android.com/accessories/aoa2.html].

Android devices with version above 4.1 supports AOA 2.0 subject to the manufacturer implementation of the protocol.

To know if an android device supports AOA 2.0, AOA defines a USB control request which returns the AOA version supported by the device.

App may be required depending on the functionality of accessory being developed. Lets say if you just wanted to stream audio and control basic functions like Play/Pause, Next/Forward etc. you can use the default Google Play Music or any other media player apps. You can make use of HID support by AOA 2.0, for controlling the app.

JVC 2014 model car stereos supports AOA 2.0 via Firmware update from their website [http://www.jvc.net/cs/car/firmware/2014/aoa/index.html]. Currently this is the only product that I know of which supports AOA 2.0. There may be others also outside.